# A link (href) inside a pre-formatted block <pre> in a markdown file

Tags: html, hyperlink, markdown, pre

I'm new to `md` and `html` and have been struggling with the following issue, **How do I embed a link inside of a `<pre>`** "data as per the example below" ***`<pre> block`**?

Example, I'm trying to do the following:

## Folder Strcture & Content

```
    ├── t_databases  
    │   └── MongoDB-Go.md
    └── t_webdev
        ├── editor-Swagger.md
        └── pacenter code herekages-Go.md
```

and inside of the "tree" structure, I would like to embed the links to those particular directories/files. I've tried using `<href>` as well as the standard `[]()` with little success.

Any help / insight will be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: Using just MarkDown syntax, I don't think so(?) But with html `pre` tags, yes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13841386/is-it-possible-to-use-an-a-tag-within-a-pre-tag. The linked question points to a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QcaV6/1/) that also seems to work in markdown.

Comment: @Calculuswhiz I attempted that and it didn't work:  
<pre>
  ├── <a href=”https://github.com/” target=”_blank”>t_databases</a>  
 </pre>
It doesn't display the `html` code, but the link isn't clickable either.

Comment: After testing it, it seems that the href attribute has to start with `http://`.

Comment: @Calculuswhiz do you mind sharing your code with me please, I have it like that but with `https` which I assume should work to, but doesn't?

Comment: In your question's markdown, I was able to get it to work with `<a href="https://google.com">MongoDB-Go.md</a>`, at least in the preview.

Comment: @Calculuswhiz I was able to to thanks, but it doesn't work for the `t_databases` entry?

Comment: What's the URL?

Comment: It's a GitHub repo, it seems that the issue was with copy and pasting and the `"` not being correct, thanks for all of your assitance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Calculuswhiz for your help,

In order to do what was intended perform the following:

```html
<pre>
    ├── <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">t_databases</a>  
    │   └── <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">MongoDB-Go.md</a>
    └── <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">t_webdev</a>  
        ├── <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">editor-Swagger.md</a>  
        └── <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">packages-Go.md</a>  
</pre>
```

> P.S. ensure that your inverted commas are correct `"` and not `”`